# Problem deleting from mySQL database with delete query (404 not Found)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I have constructed a mySQL database, and I have a React.js page with items listed with delete buttons. On the click of each delete button it should remove the item. However it does not work in my case. I have tried restarting my node server, and refreshing the db table as well as refreshing the react page. None have solved the issue. I have tried multiple other things as a result of youtube and google searches but none seem to be precise in what problem i am having.

Here is the code below. Is there anything noticeable that might be causing this issue?

index.js (this is the node server file)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "Legion101!",
  database: "cruddatabase",
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/api/get", (req, res) => {
  const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM scrap_numbers";
  db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.post("/api/insert", (req, res) => {
  const department = req.body.department;
  const summary = req.body.summary;

  const sqlInsert =
    "INSERT INTO scrap_numbers (department, summary) VALUES (?,?)";
  db.query(sqlInsert, [department, summary], (err, result) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

app.delete("/api/delete/:department", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.department;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE from scrap_numbers where department = ?";

  db.query(sqlDelete, name, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 3001");
});
```

If I should also post the App.js file please let me know.
The Database has a department column and summary column. After further testing i have found the error to be a 404 not found error. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you know if its running the delete and failing OR If its not even running the delete method?

Comment: did the api has been trigger? did devtool show network detail? you need to trace everything to find which step failed.

Comment: not just post your server side code

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not know either, I get no errors when I run. How could I figure this out? Is there a place to insert a console.log to check?

Comment: You have debuggers right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have never used one but i will try.

Comment: You don't respond to the request so even if the delete query works you're likely to get `408 request timeout` you need to call `res.send(..)` or other methods to response to the client.

Comment: I have changed the value of the delete query to 

```app.delete("/api/delete/:department", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.params.department;
  const sqlDelete = "DELETE from scrap_numbers where department = 'rrr'"; ```

and now i get an error, 404 uncaught (in promise)

the rrr is the name of one of the data pieces